# Multi save data in a sub table base on primary table auto running number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 2 tables in SQL Server 2005

1. tblEmployee (Emp_No INT, Emp_Name NVARCHAR(50)
2. tblEducation (Edu_No INT, Edu_Name NVARCHAR(50), Emp_No)

Emp_No and Edu_No fields are auto increase number.

with relationship 1 to many

I want to create stored procedure to save data both tables in the same time.
Ex. Enter data

```
Emp_No  Emp_Name    
1           Jonh    

Edu_No  Edu_Name    Emp_No
1          IT         1
2       Bussiness     1
3       Marketing     1
```

Please help. thanks.

Comment: Ok, so what have your tried and what are you having problems with specifically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the following procedure will work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_both
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tblEmployee(Emp_Name) VALUES('John')
  DECLARE @emp_key int
  SET @emp_key = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
   INSERT INTO tblEducation(Edu_Name, Emp_No)  VALUES('IT',@emp_key);
   INSERT INTO tblEducation(Edu_Name, Emp_No)  VALUES('Business',@emp_key);
   INSERT INTO tblEducation(Edu_Name, Emp_No)  VALUES('Marketing',@emp_key);
END
```

Comment: this case; if i create parameter for stored proc: Emp_Name and Edu_Name. 
in vb.net i pass value to parameter it will save only one time data. Ex Emp_Name="Jonh", Edu="IT". 
how to code in vb.net to save 1 record to tblEmployee and save multi records to tblEducation in the same time.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @emID  int
INERT INTO tblEmployee(Emp_Name) VALUES('NAME_OF_EM');

@emID   = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

-- INSET Education
INERT INTO tblEducation (Edu_Name, Emp_No) VALUES('IT', emID   );
INERT INTO tblEducation (Edu_Name, Emp_No) VALUES('Bussiness', emID   );
```

You can get last auto  increase number by SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: this case; if i create parameter for stored proc: Emp_Name and Edu_Name. 
in vb.net i pass value to parameter it will save only one time data. Ex Emp_Name="Jonh", Edu="IT". 
how to code in vb.net to save 1 record to tblEmployee and save multi records to tblEducation in the same time.